# Spring @Autowired not working and returning null

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I have problems on `@Autowired` in Spring:

MailSender.java

```
package com.example.package.util;

@Component
public class MailSender {
    @Autowired
    public MailSender(VelocityEngine velocityEngine, JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.velocityEngine = velocityEngine;
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public void send() {
        // Dosomething
    }

    private final VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

    private final JavaMailSender mailSender;
}
```

MailService.java

```
package com.example.package.service;

@Service
public class MailService {
    public void sendEmail(String email) {
        // mailSender is always null
        String mailBody = mailSender.send();
    }

    // Autowired here is not working
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myMailSender")
    private MailSender mailSender;

    // Autowired here is working
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
}
```

Configuration

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.package" />

<!-- Mail Service -->
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="classpath:/mails" />
    <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="false" />
</bean>
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.mailgun.org" />
    <property name="username" value="postmaster@testzilla.org" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="myMailSender" 
        class="com.example.package.service.MailService">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
</bean>
```

As I mentioned above, the mailSender object is always `null` in `MailService` class.

Maybe there's a conflict in mailSender object in `MailSender` class and `MailService` class. The name of variables are the same, but they are different.

So I tried to rename the variables, but still not working.

Unit Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:test-spring-context.xml"})
public class MailSenderTest {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myMailSender")
    private MailSender mailSender;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String templatePath = "/verifyEmail.vm";
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        System.out.println(mailSender);

        String mailBody = mailSender.getMailContent(templatePath, model);
        System.out.println(mailBody);
    }
}
```

When I ran the test case, I got following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.example.package.util.MailSender com.example.package.service.UserService.mailSender; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.package.util.MailSender] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=testzillaMailSender)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.package.util.MailSender] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=testzillaMailSender)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 56 more
```

Can you help me with it? Thx.

Comment: Post the full configuration file

Comment: @Reimeus I've posted it.

Comment: What is the package name for `MailService`?

Comment: `com.example.package.service.MailService`

Comment: @Reimeus Please look at the end of the question.

Comment: @HowardShieh is that what you have posted unter `Configuration` the file `test-spring-context.xml`?

Comment: @Jens Yes. But the `test-spring-context.xml` and `dispatcher-servlet.xml` are almost the same.

Comment: @HowardShieh Is your UnitTest running?

Comment: It cannot be null if it is a spring managed bean. Spring will satisfy all `@Autowired` properties or fail to start your application. Make sure that you use the Spring Managed instance of `MailService`  and aren't constructing new instances yourself.

Comment: Your xml defines the `MailService`  as `myMailSender` while the type in your `MailService` is `MailSender`. You have the problem of self referencing which leads to eager instantiation of your beans. Your configuration is a mess and a unfortunate mix of xml and annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MailService` class is not being managed by spring. One way is to add annotation(Like @Service) to let spring handle it for you. E.g.

```
@Service
public class MailService {
    public void sendEmail(String email) {
        String templatePath = "/verifyEmail.vm";
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("email", email);

        // mailSender is always null
        String mailBody = mailSender.getMailContent(templatePath, model);
    }

    // Autowired here is not working
    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;
}
```

Comment: I've added it. I forgot to tell you. - -|||

Comment: @HowardShieh do you have componenent scan enable in your xml e.g.       `<context:annotation-config  />
       <context:component-scan base-package="com" />`

Comment: I've enabled it, I forgot to tell you again. >_<

Comment: @HowardShieh I saw your updated code and inside xml you have defined bean  `myMailSender` which should be of type `com.example.package.service.MailSender` not `com.example.package.service.MailService` because you are trying to inject it via `@Qualifier(myMailSender)` to field of type `MailSender`. Just re-examine your xml carefully to avoid such errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add on the config xml 
`<context:component-scan base-package="package.of.your.service"/>`

in order spring pick this up.

From what I can see on your configuration you have only `<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.package" />` . My guessing is that this is in a different package.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong in there.

You seem to be using an unfortunate mixture of XML and Java config. Your `MailSender` has been annotated as a `@Component`, so you don't need to have any XML to define it (assuming that your component scans are defined correctly).

Also, it does not have a no-arg constructor, so the mechanism you're trying to use in the XML is not valid.

Additionally in the classes which expect it to be autowired, they are putting the `@Qualifier("myMailSender")` annotation on the field. The `MailSender` has not been named, so there is no `MailSender` with that name. You can possibly just remove the `@Qualifier` annotation. However if you do need to ensure that it's a specific bean from a multitude of options, then you should name it in the `@Controller` annotation like so:

```
@Component("myMailSender")
```